# Angular Formly File Upload - File Path, Not Contents Being Displayed

Tags: angular, angular-formly

I am attempting to build a form that allows for file uploads using Angular (v12) and Formly (v5). I have referenced Formly File Input [example](https://formly.dev/examples/other/input-file) and implemented my solution accordingly.

In `app.module` the Formly config is as follows:

```
    FormlyModule.forRoot({
      validators: [
        {
          name: 'email',
          validation: EmailValidator
        },
        {
          name: 'zip',
          validation: ZipValidator
        }
      ],
      extras: { lazyRender: true },
      types: [
        { name: 'repeater', component: QuestionRepeaterComponent },
        { name: 'file', component: FormlyFieldFile, wrappers: ['form-field'] },
      ],
    }),
```

The `FormlyFieldFile` component:

```
import { FormControl } from '@angular/forms';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { FieldType } from '@ngx-formly/material/form-field';

@Component({
    selector: 'formly-field-file',
    template: `
    <input type="file" [formControl]="formControl" [formlyAttributes]="field">
  `,
})
export class FormlyFieldFile extends FieldType {
    formControl!: FormControl;


}
```

Note: I had to declare the `formControl` property as a `FormControl` to avoid a compiler error in Angular 12.

And `FileValueAccessor`

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, ControlValueAccessor } from '@angular/forms';

@Directive({
  // tslint:disable-next-line
  selector: 'input[type=file]',
  host: {
    '(change)': 'onChange($event.target.files)',
    '(blur)': 'onTouched()',
  },
  providers: [
    { provide: NG_VALUE_ACCESSOR, useExisting: FileValueAccessor, multi: true },
  ],
})
// https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/7341
export class FileValueAccessor implements ControlValueAccessor {
  value: any;
  onChange = (_: any) => { };
  onTouched = () => { };

  writeValue(value: any) { }
  registerOnChange(fn: any) { this.onChange = fn; }
  registerOnTouched(fn: any) { this.onTouched = fn; }
}


/**  Copyright 2018 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
    Use of this source code is governed by an MIT-style license that
    can be found in the LICENSE file at http://angular.io/license */
```

The logic for building the form:

```
  public buildDocUploadForm(docOptions: Array<DropdownOption>) {
    var fFields = new Array<FormlyFieldConfig>();
    var fileF = this.buildFormlyField("file", "upload", { label: "Document File", required: true });
    var empF = this.buildFormlyField("input", "obj.empID", { label: "Employee ID", disabled: true, required: true });
    var docID = this.buildFormlyField("native-select", "obj.doc.id", { label: "Document Type", required: true, options: docOptions });
    var fNameF = {
      key: 'obj.fileName',
      type: 'input',
      hideExpression: `model.obj.doc == undefined || model.obj.doc.id == '${this.HRDOC_OTHER_ID}'`,
      templateOptions: {
        label: 'Display Name'
      }
    };

    fFields.push(fileF);
    fFields.push(empF);
    fFields.push(docID);
    fFields.push(fNameF);
    return fFields;
  }

  private buildFormlyField(type: string, key: string, templateOptions?: any, validators?: any,
    hideExpression?: string, expressionProperty?: any) {
    var f: any = {
      key: key,
      type: type,
      templateOptions: templateOptions
    };
    if (validators) {
      f["validators"] = validators;
    }
    if (hideExpression) {
      f["hideExpression"] = hideExpression;
    }
    if (expressionProperty) {
      f["expressionProperties"] = expressionProperty;
    }
    return f;
  }
```

The actual form is in my `UploadResourceDialogComponent`:

```
export class UploadResourceDialogComponent implements OnInit {

  form = new FormGroup({});
  fields: FormlyFieldConfig[] = [];
  model: FileUpload = {
    obj: new HrEmpDoc(this.data.empId),
    upload: undefined
  }

  constructor(
    @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: { empId: string },
    private uploadService: ResourceService,
    private empService: EmployeeService,
    private formlyBuilder: FormlyBuilderService,
    private optBuilder: OptionBuilderService,
    public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<UploadResourceDialogComponent>
  ) {

  }


  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.uploadService
      .getDocs()
      .subscribe(res =>
        this.fields = this.formlyBuilder.buildDocUploadForm(this.optBuilder.mapToDropdownOptions(res, "id", "title"))
      );
  }


  onSubmit() {
    if (this.form.valid) {
      this.empService.addDoc(this.data.empId, this.model.upload!, this.model.obj)
        .subscribe(res => this.dialogRef.close(true));

    }
  }

}
```

The HTML for the component

```
<h4>Add Resource </h4>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <formly-form [form]="form" [fields]="fields" [model]="model">
    </formly-form>
    {{model | json}}
    <button mat-button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

... and the model used.

```
export interface FileUpload {
    upload: File | undefined
    obj: any


}
```

The form displays as expected. However, instead of coming through as a Blob, File, a byte array, etc, the file simply comes through as a string, i.e. the model for a completed form: `{ "obj": { "id": 0, "fileID": "", "createdDateTime": "2021-09-30T12:29:34.108Z", "empID": "1002397", "doc": { "isInternal": false, "docCat": "OT", "id": "I9" }, "fileName": "Test" }, "upload": "C:\\fakepath\\Screenshot_2021-06-08_13-39-01.png" }`

What am I doing wrong? I have implemented file uploads in Angular previously (using just Reactive Forms) and never encountered this issue before?

Comment: I think it's because the html atribute `value` of `<input type="file">` contains a file path. I noticed that your implementation of `FileValueAccessor` actually does nothing, you are passing $event.target.files to onChange() but it's empty

Comment: Thanks for the info @icekson. For the `FileValueAccessor`, I used the one provided in Stackblitz example from Formly : https://stackblitz.com/angular/kbknmvyayxp?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts  However, I might work on modifying it and seeing if I can get it working. Thanks.